# Сжать массив, удалив из него все 0 и, заполнить освободившиеся справа элементы значениями –1, C#

Tags: c#

Начал знакомство с языком C# после изучения C. 
Вопрос, можно ли как то упростить в шарпе эту задачу?
Не кидайте сильно камнями, я новичок))
Спасибо!

p.s. удалить элементы это видимо подразумевается сдвиг элементов.

```
        int[] mas = new int[] { 1,5,8,1,0,2,1,0,3,0 };
        int n = mas.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (mas[i] == 0)
            {
                n--;
                for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
                {
                    mas[j] = mas[j + 1];
                }
                mas[n] = -1;
                i--;
            }
        }
```

//на выходе {1 5 8 1 2 1 3 -1 -1 -1}

Comment: добавь пример входного и выходного массивов

Comment: Скрин результата работы?

Comment: Не скрин, а сами данные, можешь что-то вроде такого: сначала было так [...], вместо `...` значения, а нужно чтобы стало так: [...] вместе `...` новые значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По тексту задачи должен быть сдвиг, иначе откуда возьмутся "освободившиеся справа элементы". Если нужна максимальная эффективность, то так:

```
var a = new [] {1,0,2,3,0,0,4,5,0,6,7,8,9,0,0,0,0};
var z = 0;//количество найденных нулей
for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
  if(a[i] == 0) z++;
  else a[i-z] = a[i];
}
for(int i = a.Length - z; i < a.Length; i++)
{
  a[i] = -1;
}
//на выходе {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}
```

Сложность O(N). Есть небольшой оверхед по фиктивному сдвигу начальных ненулевых элементов. Будет ли более эффективно делать предварительную проверку на необходимость переноса `z > 0`? Можно померить, но я почти уверен, что разница будет в пределах погрешности измерений.

---

Обращение к длине массива - константная операция, длина не вычисляется и зафиксирована в структуре массива и некоторых других коллекций.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Если не принципиально использовать именно массив:

```
List<int> mas = new List<int>();
int n = 30;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    mas.Add(rand.Next(-1, 5));
    Console.Write(mas[i] + " ");
}
mas.RemoveAll(x => x == 0);
int count = mas.Count();
for (int i = count; i < n; i++)
    mas.Add(-1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, задание именно на массив